# how to enable code folding in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-folding

in android studio right click on my code and **folding->collapse or expand all** does not work. also **Ctrl +  or Ctrl -** does not work.
how to enable code folding in android studio?

Answer (score 1):

Try this short cut for Mac `cmd+shift+'-'` to collapse all, and `cmd+shift+'+'` to expand all. I take it for windows it should be something like `Ctrl+shift+'-'` and `Ctrl+shift+'+'`